# Minted listings spanning across multiple pages with caption

Tags: captions, minted, code, lncs

I'm using the lncs class and I'm trying to have long code highlighted with minted to span across multiple pages with a caption. According to the minted documentation, a new environment is needed. I'm using the caption package.
It works perfectly with a document class such as article, but not with the lncs class.

This is what I have so far:

```
\documentclass{llncs}

\usepackage{caption}

\newenvironment{longlisting}{\captionsetup{type=listing}}{}
\usepackage[cache=false,outputdir=../build]{minted}

\begin{document}
%
\title{Contribution Title\thanks{Supported by the Machine Learning teaching team.}}
% 
\author{The author\orcidID{123456}}
%
\authorrunning{F. Author et al.}
%
\institute{An Institute\\
    \email{\{someone,anotherone\}@fantasy.com}}
%
\maketitle              % typeset the header of the contribution
%
\begin{abstract}
    The abstract
    \keywords{First keyword  \and Second keyword \and Another keyword.}
\end{abstract}
%
\section{First Section}
% 
\begin{longlisting}
    \begin{minted}{python}
    # This program does amazing stuff!
    import numpy as np
    print('Hello, world!')
    \end{minted}
    \caption{This is the caption}
    \label{lst:long}
\end{longlisting}
\end{document}
```

When I compile, I get the following error messages:

> Unsupported document class (or package) detected, (caption)
>   usage of the caption package is not recommended. See the caption
>   package documentation for explanation.
>
> Package caption Warning: \caption will not be redefined since it's
>   already (caption)                redefined by a document class or
>   package which is (caption)                unknown to the caption
>   package. See the caption package documentation for explanation.

I tried with the option

```
\captionsetup{compatibility=false}
```

but then I get the warning message:

> Package caption Warning: Forced redefinition of \caption since the
>   (caption)                unsupported(!) package option
>   `compatibility=false' (caption)                was given. See the
>   caption package documentation for explanation.

Is there any solution to this?

Comment: It appears the caption package is incompatible (forbidden) with llncs.  All you really need is `\expandafter\def\csname @captype\endcsname{listings}` or `\makeatletter \def\@captype{listings} \makeatother`.  This assumes that the float class listings exists (not a minted user).

Comment: I relatively new to LaTeX. Could you please explain me how to use the concepts above and the difference between them?

Comment: The @ symbol is used to protect system commands etc. from being used by the unwashed masses.  \makeatletter removes that constraint, and \makeatother restores it.  \csname ...\endcsname can also use @ symbols, although that is not its primary function.  The \expandafter allows \csname to expand before \def.